# Receiving errors when trying to pass function into axios.then and catch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/login', {
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password
            }, {
                    headers: {
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "",
                    }
                })
                .then(function (response) { this.onloginSuccess(response) })
                .catch(function (error) { this.onLoginFail(error)});
```

I have this axios post that is suppose to handle the response like the following:

```
onloginSuccess = (response) => {
        console.log(response)
        this.setState({
            buttonDisable: false
        });

        sessionStorage.setItem('uuid', response.value.data.uuid)
        sessionStorage.setItem('bearertoken', response.value.data.bearertoken)


        this.props.history.push({ pathname: '/dashboard' })
    }
```

And the error like the following:

```
onloginFail = (error) => {
        NotificationManager.error(error.response.data.message, 'Error!', 5000);
        this.setState({
            buttonDisable: false
        });
    }
```

I keep the following errors:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'onLoginFail' of undefined
    at eval (index.js?8a7d:95)
```

and when I delete onLoginFail I get

```
index.js?8a7d:94 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'onloginSuccess' of undefined
    at eval (index.js?8a7d:94)
```

Comment: I bet this is undefined in `this.onLoginFail`, you forgot to bind the function to this.

Answer (score 1):

```
.then(function (response) { this.onloginSuccess(response) })
```

Change it to an arrow function.

```
.then((response) => this.onloginSuccess(response))
```

Regular functions get their value of `this` based on how their invoked. The function gets invoked with no particular context, so `this` is set to the window object (in non-strict mode) or undefined (in strict mode, which you appear to be in). Arrow functions on the other hand get their value of `this` from where they are defined and so `this` will equal the same thing it equaled at the time you called axios.post.

Alternatively, since onLoginSuccess is itself an arrow function, and the parameters are already in the right order, you could just pass a reference to onLoginSuccess:

```
.then(this.onloginSuccess)
```

Comment: Hey, so I was able to get onLoginSuccess to go through however now after onLoginSuccess goes through I get this error:

index.js?8a7d:95 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this3.onLoginFail is not a function
    at eval (index.js?8a7d:95)

Comment: I made that change and this is what I get

Comment: make sure the capitalization lines up. In the sample you provided us, you called it onloginFail (with a lowercase l) in one spot, and onLoginFail in another.

Comment: Hey Nicholas, I just checked and the capitalization is correct.

Comment: Where are you defining the `axios.post`? It's unclear from your question.

Comment: from a function named handleLogin

Comment: I binded handleLogin with this.handleLogin.bind(this) in the constructor

Comment: Actually you were right it was not bounded. However now  it is going the catch even though there is no error.